# Use `.navbar-fixed-top` for large screens, and `.navbar-static-top` for smaller screens

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass, bootstrap-sass

I'm using Bootstrap on my site, and I have chosen to use a navbar fixed to the top of the screen for navigation on desktop browsers, where there's plenty of screen real-estate available. This is done in bootstrap by using the `.navbar-fixed-top` class for my navbar.

On smaller screens though I'd prefer to use a static navbar which scrolls with the rest of the page content, since this conserves vertical screen real-estate on smaller devices where such space is at a premium.

Naturally, I turned to the obvious way of doing this using css media queries:

```
#site-header
{
  @extend .navbar, .navbar-default;

  @media (max-width: $screen-xs-max) {
    @extend .navbar-static-top;
  }

  @media (min-width: $screen-sm-min) {
    @extend .navbar-fixed-top;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this gives me the error message:

```
You may not @extend an outer selector from within @media.
You may only @extend selectors within the same directive.
```

Based on the error message, that seems like a very deliberate limitation in SASS. Is there a way around this other than using JavaScript to apply classes dynamically?

Essentially my problem is similar to [Extending selectors from within media queries with Sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840918/removing-duplicate-css-with-sass-media-and-extend), except that I'm looking to extend a class which is defined in a library (Bootstrap), so I don't have the option of converting the definitions of `.navbar-static-top` and `.navbar-fixed-top` into mixins or changing their definition in any way, as all of the existing answers to that question currently suggest doing.

Comment: @cimmanon My problem is indeed similar to that, but since I'm looking to extend a class provided by a library (Bootstrap), the solutions proposed in that answer which suggest "use a mixin instead" or "define the class inside the media query instead of trying to extend it there" aren't very helpful in my case. So I guess maybe this *is* a different question?

Comment: The fact that neither of those options are viable for your situation is irrelevant:  those are the only options that exist.  If you don't like them, I suggest you take your complaint to the maintainers of Sass (or Bootstrap).

Comment: @cimmanon I don't know, my gut is telling me that two questions can't really be duplicates if valid answers to one question don't answer the other. That kind of goes against the whole point of marking questions as duplicates IMO, which is to help future visitors find an answer to their question.

Comment: And how many questions do you think we need on SO that address the `You may not @extend an outer selector from within @media` error?  It doesn't matter where the selector you want to extend comes from (you wrote it, someone else wrote it, etc.):  the answer is and always will be the same:  you can't do that (until Sass itself changes to allow this behavior).

Comment: @cimmanon Yeah, I think I understand now that there's currently no way around this problem (short of getting SASS patched). I'm not sure it's helpful though to direct future visitors to a different question whose answers don't address the specific problem asked in this question. Perhaps instead it might be better to write an answer here which basically says "Sorry, you can't do that. Either copy the styles from Bootstrap into a mixin, apply classes dynamically with JavaScript, or...".

Comment: @cimmanon Then again though, the lack of a answer on that (rather popular) question which addresses this specific subset of that problem might be useful information in and of itself. Honestly I'm not sure... maybe a meta question is in order.

Comment: But the popular answer in the linked question *already says **you can't do that***.  Why do we need to copy that information here?

Comment: @cimmanon The thing is though, the error message already told me "you can't do that" (assuming that by "that", you mean extend an outer selector from within a media query); that's not really what this question is about. This question is about finding work-arounds to that limitation. Specifically, work-arounds which don't use JavaScript or require me to modify the definition of the class I'm extending. Apparently no such workarounds exist, but the answers to the other question don't say that, because in the scope of that question there **are** applicable workarounds.

Comment: @cimmanon Meta post here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289907/1157054 I welcome your feedback on the way I phrased the question (hopefully I didn't leave out anything important). Oh, and if you want to post an answer there please feel free. Meta seems like it would be a good place to have this discussion.

Answer (score 1):

You can write classes inside media queries and extend them. Something like this

```
#site-header {
  @extend .navbar, .navbar-default;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-static-top {
    position: static;
  }

  #site-header {
    @extend .navbar-static-top;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-fixed-to-top {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
  }

  #site-header {
    @extend .navbar-fixed-to-top;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that would work in this case, since the properties of `.navbar-fixed-top` and `.navbar-static-top` are defined by Bootstrap, not by me. I suppose I could copy the attributes out of the library and stick them in my own code file, but wouldn't that sort of defeat the purpose of having constructs like `@extend`?