# How to extend Bootstrap 4 classes by breakpoint

Tags: css, sass, media-queries, breakpoints

I want to extend certain bootstrap classes with media breakpoints (similar like bootstrap does it with `col-6`, `col-md-6`).

So I tried this:

```css
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  table.table-md-sm {
    @extend .table-sm;
  }
}
```

However that gives me the SASS compiler error «**You may not @extend selectors across media queries**».

So how can I do this with pure SASS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extending selectors from within media queries with Sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840918/extending-selectors-from-within-media-queries-with-sass)

Comment: I don't think so, because I want to extend with an existing bootstrap class `table-sm`, not my own class