# How to apply different class styles to element for different screen sizes?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

So in my project I have included Sass styles from a third party library (trough node modules). Normally nobody touches such code as it is subject to updates etc. However the design from artist requires to apply class `x` styles when its desktop and `y` class styles when its mobile to same element. I tried something like:

```
.z {
  @extend .x;
}

@include media-breakpoint-down(sm) {
    .z {
      @extend .y;
    }
}
```

But SASS doesn't allow this. `You may not @extend an outer selector from within @media`.

Another way is to duplicate the element. One has class `x` another `y`. And then show/hide them according to screen size, but that's bad for SEO and also code looks ugly.

I wonder if there is a graceful solution to this problem!?

Comment: Consider using media queries to set your styles.

Comment: Here's another question describing using a @mixin instead: [Extending Selectors within Media Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840918/extending-selectors-from-within-media-queries-with-sass)

Comment: I can NOT convert 3rd party lib classes to mixins @GabrielPetersen

Comment: @Lae the above example show, that media queries can't really be used for extending existing classes.

Comment: @Lae no it wont and the link is already pasted in 2nd comment