# SASS: @extend inside of @media query

Tags: css, sass

I have simple code with SCSS code where is **@extend** within **@media query**.

SCSS complier gives me error on both of this variations:

**VARIATION 1:**

```
%dark-theme {
    background: $dark-background;
}

%light-theme {
    background: $light-background;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
    body {
        @extend %light-theme;
    }
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    body {
        @extend %dark-theme;
    }
}
```

**VARIATION 2**

```
%dark-theme {
    background: $dark-background;
}

%light-theme {
    background: $light-background;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
    @extend %light-theme;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    @extend %dark-theme;
}
```

Is there any solution how I can do the **@extend** in basic element and also in **@media query**?

Comment: This may help answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840918/extending-selectors-from-within-media-queries-with-sass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `@extend` inside a media query.
What you can do it the other way around though, use the media query inside the class you are extending.

```
%dark-theme {
    @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
        background: $dark-background;
    }
}

%light-theme {
    @media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
        background: $light-background;
    }
}

body {
    @extend %light-theme;
    @extend %dark-theme;
}
```

mixin is also an alternative

Answer (score 2):

...or you can simply use mixins:

```
@mixin dark-theme {
    background: $dark-background;
}

@mixin light-theme {
    background: $light-background;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
   body {
    @include light-theme;
   }
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  body {
    @include dark-theme;
  }
}
```